# minimum height 100% for a div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a simple solution for this layout.
This is the simplified html.

```
<div class='wrapper'>
<div class='header'></div>
<div class='middle'> TEXT </div>
<div class='footer'></div>
</div>
```

Header and footer have a fixed height in pixels.
middle can have a variable height, depending on the content.
I want wrapper to have a minimum height of 100%. So if the text inside middle is small, the middle div should expand to fill the browser page. And if it's too long, the *whole page* should be scrollable.

Is this possible easily? Maybe changing something in the layout?

Comment: You want middle to fill the whole page? So you want to make users scroll to see the footer no matter what? Or do you want footer to be at the bottom and just have middle occupy all the space down to that?

Comment: The real problem of this layout is that I need a minimum height of 100%, but it can be longer, even more than the browser height. I found something like this http://jsfiddle.net/HebB6/1/, if you change "content" to a lot of text, scrollbars appears, and the footer is still at the bottom. But I don't like using display : table...

Comment: @deviantseev `height:100%` along won't solve this. you need that along with `min-height:100%` on the `.wrapper` class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's your solution: http://jsfiddle.net/S4akv/1/

You do NOT want to set a hard height for the `.middle`. If your content is only a few lines then you will end up with scrollbars where none are needed.

With a header and footer, you also don't want `height: 100%` on your `.middle` class because it will push your footer down, forcing a scrollbar no matter what. You *also* don't want a clear-cut `height:100%` because most browsers will interpret this as 100% of the browser height, so when you resize your browser to be larger, either the height won't change or the footer won't move.

The best solution here is to have your wrapper and any associating backgrounds attached to that. Depending on the content within your `.middle` div this answer could change, but given the simple parameters this is the most elegant way to do it.

the secret is to make sure that all containing elements have a height set. reason being, any block element with `height: 100%` will only be 100% of the area containing it. in this case you need to set height for middle, wrapper and `body, html`

```
body,html { height: 100%; margin:0; padding:0; }
.wrapper { min-height: 100%; width: 100%; background-color: red; position:relative; padding-bottom: 200px; }
.header { height: 200px; width: 100%; background-color: blue; }
.middle {  }
.footer { height: 200px; width: 100%; background-color: green; position:absolute; bottom: 0; }
```

If you have nested content within `.middle` that also needs to be 100% height there is a better way, using a combination of height, absolute positioning and negative margins. There are a million ways to skin a cat. Well, a handful at least :)

**edited to add padding to `.wrapper` to make room for footer. The bottom padding of wrapper must be the same height as the footer**

Comment: The problem with this it's that if the middle is very long, it overflows the footer.

Comment: the fiddle you mean? i caught that in the post and edited it shortly after i posted this - looks like i forgot to update the fiddle, though. it's fixed. with `min-height` it won't overflow the footer. `height:100%` would, though

Comment: There is still one problem...if the text is very long, the footer goes over the last lines of text. I suppose I could set padding-bottom in the middle div...

Comment: Ah, you are right! Not just the last line, though, a whole 200px. I added `padding-bottom: 200px;` to the wrapper css to allow enough room for the footer, which is absolutely positioned. In the previous version this meant the whole footer was floating above the wrapper contents. Sorry about that!